# My phone's wifi wont stay closed

Tags: wi-fi

Every time I close my wifi, it switches back on straight away. I got a Moto G 2nd generation with android 6.0. How do i stop this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a power user, the following things come to my mind for troubleshooting such an issue -

1. Try rebooting the phone.
2. Use any of the reputed android utility apps to check the status of phone software/hardware.
3. Trying out a soft reset of the phone with a data backup.

If all these fail, then definitely contacting Motorola or a service center for assistance will help.

Comment: ive done 1, can you suggest any apps for 2? thanks for the help

Comment: i figured it out just now, it turns out to be because of avast anti theft app which secretly kept the wifi on because i changed my sim card so that it could locate my phone

Comment: Ahh! The classic case of Companies spying on us :) Glad, I was of some help to you while you sorted it out.